# Crossrider : How to Uninstall browser extension

Tags: browser-extension, crossrider

I created browser extension using crossrider code, we can install this extension in all 4 browsers(Chrome,IE,Firefox,Safari).After installation a icon will be displayed beside the url. If we click on that icon a popup will displayed which contains one button

1)delete/uninstall

so, what I have to do is If user click on "uninstall/delete" button then the extension will remove from the browser.How can I achieve this functionality using crossrider code.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, extension removal by the extension itself is not supported by any  browser regardless of which platform the extension is written with. So whilst the Crossrider platform tries to provide as much common functionality as possible, I'm afraid this feature is not available.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I hope this feature will come soon. @Sholmo

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. Chrome+Opera definitely support self-removal. Technically/in theory, Firefox/IE addons can also remove themselves. Only Safari extensions can definitely not remove themselves.

Answer (score 0):

- Chrome extensions can remove themselves using [`chrome.management.uninstallSelf`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-uninstallSelf). This does not require any permissions.
- Firefox add-ons are trusted at the same level as the browser, so it is technically possible to remove the add-on. I don't know the API from the top of my head, but you could look at the source code of the Addon Manager for inspiration.
- Internet Explorer extensions are binary code. Depending on how they're implemented, they might be able to uninstall themself. If you've written a basic BHO that runs in Internet Explorer's (low-integrity) process, then you cannot fully uninstall the extension, because it cannot write to the registry, or remove files from `C:\Program Files`.
- Safari: Extensions don't have any method to remove themselves.